How to access a @MainActor annotated Singleton from an async function correctly?
I have a class with a Singleton I want to use throughout my app like:
class InteractorManager: ObservableObject {
  @MainActor static let shared = InteractorManager()
  
  private init() { }
  
  func initialDataLoading() async throws {
    try await // loading code
  }
}

I now have an async function like this:
  private func handleDataInitialization() async {
    do {
      try await InteractorManager.shared.initialDataLoading()
    } catch {
      // Catch error
    }
  }

The problem: If I use Product -> Run all works fine. I can use this code, the compiler allows it to run. But if I use Product -> Archive it cannot build as this code fails. It shows the error: Sending main actor-isolated value of type 'InteractorManager' with later accesses to nonisolated context risks causing data races
So I tried to assure the MainActor is used. But it does not matter what I tried yet, the error still appears when I try to archive (I guess as the compiler is more strict in this case).
What I tried:

Annoting the function as MainActor like:

  @MainActor
  private func handleDataInitialization() async {
    do {
      try await InteractorManager.shared.initialDataLoading()
    } catch {
      // Catch the error
    }
  }


Use it in Task { @MainActor in like

  private func handleDataInitialization() async {
    Task { @MainActor in
      do {
        try await InteractorManager.shared.initialDataLoading()
      } catch {
        // Catch the error
      }
    }
  }


Delete Derived Data, Clean Build folder and restart XCode.

So I am searching for a solution to use an @MainActor isolated shared Singleton from an async function as XCode does not allow me to use those suggested (As said, only for stricter archive compiler)

What point of making static constant available only in main thread? Better to mark with MainActor methods of InteractorManager or whole class.

P.S. Check compilation settings, looks like you have different parameters for strict concurrency for Debug and Release configurations

1, in 2 async is pointless. But singletons are not considered good practice by many

You might want to annotate the whole class InteractorManager with @MainActor. When you call it from the MainActor context, you do not need to call initialDataLoading() async anymore. However, this does not solve all the problems: you still need additional logic in your InteractorManager , that handles potentially multiple overlapping async calls of initialDataLoading().

Yes, decided to remove the singleton pattern and work with DI instead.

That looks like a Swift 6 error which now requires proper code design - because async funcs can be called simultaneously the can't be in a class instance methods because that would corrupt the instance vars. Instead the async func should go in a struct and you can put it in the Environment so it can be used across the View structs, e.g.
struct InteractorController {
  func loadData() async throws -> [Item] {
    return try await // loading code
  }
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    @Entry var interactorController = InteractorController()
}

struct InteractorView: View {
    @Environment(\.interactorController) var interactorController: InteractorController
    @State var items: [Item] = [] // or Result<[Item], Error>
    var body: some View {
        // Views
        .task {
            items = try? await interactorController.load() // or model.items
        }
    }
}

The results could be set on a model object instead of @State. A Result type could be used to bounce the error or valid results to body. If InteractorController was a protocol then the controller implementation in the environment could be mocked for Previews.

This would still require some thing  which handles the function loadData(). Since it is async, it can potentially overlap. Thus, this "thing" which handles these async function calls,  obviously has to manage mutable state (unless overlapping calls are tolerated, which, in most cases is not allowed), is likely a class, and it also needs to be a  shared instance, which makes it a singleton.

The loadData can overlap but that doesn't matter. Setting the items can't overlap because .task is MainActor. Also if the items were set on a model which is a @MainActor object then that can't overlap either.
